# Retrieving data across 5 tables in has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

**Issue**: Is there a better way to model the following or create a basic recommendation system than the database diagram below?  If an extremely lengthy answer is necessary, you could instead just point me in the right direction and suggest things to research further.

I'm building a rudimentary event recommendation system by allowing users to answer questions and storing their user-answer relationship in the responses model.  Each question's answer relates to a tag.  Each event is also tagged.  Thus, I should be able to provide users with recommended events via selecting matching tags and using this 5 table relationship.  However, it seems like I would have to go through several has_many :through relationships in order to accomplish this, which I don't believe is preferred using Rails.

Would it be better to instead create a relationship from users to events via a background rake task or something, computing the relationship after questions are answered?  Am I missing the concepts completely here and looking at this from the wrong angle?  Eventually this system would be replaced with a more robust algorithm, perhaps using Mahout or something, but for now I'm just trying to get a simple proof of concept working.

Here's a link to the database diagram: [Database Diagram](http://i.imgur.com/T2bDY.png)